# CSS: force radio input to checked

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a site on which I can only add my custom CSS.

**I know CSS is not the place to modify content, but sometimes it is not possible to change eighter HTML or use JS.**

So I want to select (checked) a certain radio input.

There is a [workaround to replace content](https://blog.escapecreative.com/how-to-replace-text-with-css/) such as texts by CSS, by hiding an element and then replacing it with element:after.

What I want to achieve is to select a radio box, so my question is: how to set a property in CSS outside the style property.

```
<input type="radio" checked="" …
```

Any help highly appreciated

Best endo

Comment: you can not set `chcked=true` in css but you van target all `:checked` `radio`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

CSS has no ability to change the value or any other status of form controls (including checked, readonly, and disabled).